# get_template_directory_uri() links to child theme not parent

Tags: functions, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style, css, parent-theme

I have created a child theme of a parent theme which shows correctly on wp theme selector and activates.

I have created a `style.css` of said child theme with the following meta information:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Twenty Sixteen Child
 Theme URI:    http://localhost:888/wordpress-test/twentysixteen-child/
 Description:  My first child theme, based on Twenty Sixteen
 Author:       Juan D. Bolanos
 Author URI:   http://synchronygroup.com
 Template:     Twenty Sixteen
 Version:      1.0.0
 Tags:         black, green, white, light, dark, two-columns, three-columns, left-sidebar, right-sidebar, fixed-layout, responsive-layout, custom-background, custom-header, custom-menu, editor-style, featured-images, flexible-header, full-width-template, microformats, post-formats, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, theme-options, translation-ready, accessibility-ready, responsive-layout, infinite-scroll, post-slider, design, food, journal, magazine, news, photography, portfolio, clean, contemporary, dark, elegant, modern, professional, sophisticated
 Text Domain:  twentysixteen-child
*/
```

I have created a `function.php` file of said theme and used `wp_enqueue_styles` function as referenced [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

```
<?php
function wordpress_main_style() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'child-theme', get_stylesheet_uri());
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wordpress_main_style' );
?>
```

I have included the `wp_head()` within my `header.php` and called into my `index.php`. The stylesheets are shown on the site, as shown in inspector, but the 'parent-theme' stylesheet points to the child theme directory as apposed to the parent directory.

I have ensured that the folder names match with the inclusion of '-child' on my child theme. I have read this [documentation](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme/) to ensure nothing was incorrect.

What could be possibly missing that would cause a misdirection in the directory?

Comment: You don't need to put -child on the end of a child themes folder, that's purely convention on the part of the WPMUdev people

Comment: When you inspect your home page with developer tools, you should see a second styles.css file (your child theme version), overriding your parent styles.css file.  Within your child theme styles.css file, go ahead and make your style modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the original article:

```
Template:     twentyfourteen
```

We see that the folder `twentyfourteen` is mentioned, aka the "Twenty Fourteen" theme

Whereas you have:

```
Template:     Twenty Sixteen
```

Which is the human readable name of the theme, not the theme folder name. This is what you need to put:

```
Template:     twentysixteen
```

Comment: I replaced the template name with the folder name as suggested and saw no change in the directory path. Still goes to 'twentysixteen-child/style.css'

Comment: If this doesn't solve the problem then you should unmark it as the correct answer. Have you tried this in a clean install of the latest WordPress with only your child theme and parent theme installed?